# Combining the concept of exporting an interface with CRTP

Tags: c++, interface, crtp

One common use of an interface it to export the interface from a DLL or a shared library. This makes it possible to write a program that chooses between multiple versions of an interface by selecting which shared library to load at runtime. One very useful use of this is to write a program that can function with multiple speech engines. The speech engine libraries are loaded by the application based on user preferences.

For example, assume that you have the following interface.

```
struct ITTS
{
    virtual bool Init() = 0;
    virtual bool Shutdown() = 0;
    virtual bool ReadyToSpeak() = 0;
    virtual bool Speak(const char* str) = 0;
};
```

Then in each DLL or shared library there is an exported function GetTTS that returns a pointer to an ITTS object. This function works by returning a pointer to an object that is derived from the ITTS interface.

I have been studying CRTP and its use as an alternative to such interfaces. For example the above traditional interface would be implemented using CRTP as follows.

```
template<class T>
struct ITTS
{
    bool Init()
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->Init_();
    }
    bool Shutdown()
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->Shutdown_();
    }
    bool ReadyToSpeak()
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->ReadyToSpeak_();
    }
    bool Speak(const char* str)
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->Speak_(str);
    }
};
```

The problem is that it is not possible to define a function that returns a pointer to such an object in such a way that the application can choose between implementations of the interface at runtime.

Comment: `CRTP and its use as an alternative to such interfaces` I don't see how one can possibly be considered an alternative to the other. CRTP is an implementation technique, not an API definition technique.

Comment: Don't use CRTP in situations that call for normal polymorphic interfaces. It isn't entirely clear why you are using it. It looks like you are trying to re-invent virtual functions. Don't.